# Ebay seller where is AddItemRequest API call?

Tags: ebay-api

I'm getting this error when trying to make a publishOffer call in ebay API Explorer. It's strange that I can't find this error and related solution in the internet.

```
A user error has occurred. Invalid <ShippingPackage>
```

I have found that it has to be set in **AddItemRequest.Item.ShippingPackageDetails.ShippingPackage** it's not a buying but a selling activity.

However, I can't locate the AddItemRequest call anywhere. There's only *inventory_item* related calls that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the two versions of eBay's APIs. The `publishOffer` is an API endpoint that exists on the newer version of eBay APIs and `AddItemRequest` is an input type used for adding inventory through the older, XML based APIs (called Trading API) provided by eBay. More specifically, the `AddItemRequest` is the name of an input entity used in the [AddItem](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/additem.html) call on the Trading API which is used to create and publish a new listing on an eBay site. If you look at the input XML for this endpoint, `AddItemRequest` is the primary container in the input. Here's the first few lines of XML input to the `AddItem` API:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Item> ItemType
    <ApplicationData> string </ApplicationData>
    ...
```